# Windows 8 in monitor mode?

Tags: windows-8, display

I have accidently put my laptop to be connected to an external monitor. This was a mistake and I don't have an external monitor, but I can't get it off this mode since when I start up my laptop it forms a black screen (for obvious reasons) How do I turn it off monitor mode to get it to display back on its own screen.

Comment: What type of laptop is it?

Comment: @Omen the lapton is an acer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try key shortcut Win+P and click on "PC screen only"

Comment: He has a black screen so it will be difficult to click in the right place ...

Comment: Ohh, click or use arrows? It's a same. There are only 4 options and only one is only for "monitor mode" then all other options are correct and can be used.

Comment: Yes, I suppose trial end error with arrow keys (and enter or space?) will work. I don't know if Win+P will work on an Acer though. It does work on my Sony Vaio.

Comment: This shortcut must works on any laptop or PC with Windows. This shurtcut works on Windows for long time (on Win7 for example).